# Молодежный сленг на телевидении и в рекламе

Tags: сленг

Сегодня ко мне подошли рекламные агенты и стали предлагать "клевые" товары (как они выразились) - не буду уточнять, какие. Я говорю, что слово "клевые" не литературное и не стоит коверкать русский язык, а они развели руками: "Это наш слоган, мы ничего не можем менять".
Как вы считаете, допустим ли молодежный сленг в рекламных слоганах, на телевидении и т.д.?

Answer (score 3):

В молодежных программах сленг составляет около 50% всего лексикона ведущих. Если руководство телевидения это разрешает, значит, никому нет дела до литературных норм языка...

Comment: Ну, разрешает и допустимо - это разные вещи)))

Comment: В данном случае это как раз одно и то же. Потому что сколько бы мы ни возмущались и ни ворчали, коль разрешают - значит, будут говорить на сленге.

Answer (score 0):

Сегодня ко мне подошли рекламные агенты и стали предлагать "клевые" товары (как они выразились) - не буду уточнять **какие**.

Вам следует обратить внимание на ошибку, сделанную Вами.